# How can I work around the promises that serialport nodejs package works with

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, serial-port

I've started a project that requires communication between an arduino and a local nodejs server (*unrelated* the data will be sent via an http request or a socket to the actual remote server later on). I'm using the node package serialport. At the beginning of the serial communication, the server needs to "find" the arduino. I've decided on the following negotiation codex: 

1) the server sends a "c" character (as in connect) which the arduino is listening for

2) the arduino replies to all "c"s with another "c" which the server will be listening for

 in other words when both sides receive a "c" that means the serial connection works

However, due to serialport using promises I can't go through all available ports and check if there's an arduino (which replies with "c") there.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var Readline = require('@serialport/parser-readline');

async function tryPort(path) {
    var port = new SerialPort(path, {
        baudRate: 9600
    });
    port.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    port.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '\n' })).on('data', (data)=>{
        console.log(port);
        console.log(data);
        if (data == 'c') {
            return port;
        }
        port.close();
    });
    port.write("c", function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
}
async function connect() {
    var connection, ports = await SerialPort.list();
    for(i=0;i<ports.length;i++){
        connection = await tryPort(ports[i].path);
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (!connection) {
            console.log("no port/response found");
        }else{
            console.log(connection);
        }
    }, 3000);
}

connect();
```

I went with the assumption the variable 'connection' will be assigned the value of the port that responded correctly last because that port will take the longest to finish. Unfortunately, it seems this won't work with promises... So I'm wondering if there's any other way to accomplish it?

Comment: 1) Your `tryPort()` function doesn't really wait for the `'data'` event as I think you've intended it to.

2) In your `for` loop, you're executing the `tryPort`s in sequence, not in parallel.

Comment: @shkaper How do I execute all tryPort() instances in parallel? Or how could I make it 'wait' for the data to be returned?